# Too many SOQL queries: 101 Flow

Tags: soql, query, lookup, visual-workflow, fast-lookup

I have a FLow that allows users to enter in a list of comma separated Zip Codes that Looks Up a Zip Code record and creates a junction object between the Resource Record and the Zip Code.

If the Zip Code record doesn't exist it asks the User to Create it.

My issue is that if users want to create more than 100 Resource Zip Code (Junction Object) records Salesforce will throw a "Too many SOQL queries: 101" error. Any Ideas how I can get around this? (See Current Flow below)

I've also thought about using Fast Lookup but I don't think I can use the Decision Element in the instances where a Zip Code Record doesn't exist.

[image: Flow]

Comment: have you tried bulkifying the records in flow? 1.using fast lookups to find all valid zip codes in the flow. 2.create resource zip code records for all valid zip codes. 3.collect all invalid zip codes 4. display them in a screen for the user to correct them. repeat step 1 until all zip codes are processed

Comment: Hey Suneel, My issue here is Step 3. How do you collect Invalid Zips?
I didn't see a way to create a decision for Zip Codes not found.

Comment: Yes cory,you can write a small apex class to do that task

Comment: I was attempting to avoid Apex since I'm not sure how to write that.

Comment: Cory, if you were able to get a count of the number of entries in your comma-separated list, and tell the user to cut back if that count exceeded 100, would that solve your problem?

Comment: @AlexEdelstein That wouldn't work because typically users are adding between 200-300 zip codes. The Flow is also used to clear out the existing codes attached to the resource.